# Adjusting flex Footer position (with "translatedY" child elements) on a responsive website

Tags: html, css, flexbox, parent-child, viewport-units

I am trying to make a sticky footer with these premises:

- footer is position:fixed;
- its global height changes according to:

  - how many child .sub-menu items the user adds (may vary)
  - the media queries (that change the font-size)
  - the font-size (which is attributed in viewport units "vw")

There are two specific media instances that change the font size:

- one media query for devices/screens bellow 980px
- and one for devices/screens above 1550px

I am trying to position the footer always on the bottom of the page while focing its child elements to appear above it. However the number of .sub-menu items is forcing the footer to grow in height; as if that wasn't enough the viewport width is changing the font size, which also affect the height of the element.

```css
h1 {
font-size: 4vw;
letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
h2, h3, ul.sub-menu {
 font-size:2.3vw;
  line-height: 1.4em;
 color: black;
}

.footermenu {
        bottom:0vh;
        left:0vw;
        position: fixed;
        width: 95vw;
        padding-right: 5vw; 
     height: 55vh; /*this seems to help but it is not reliable enough*/
     z-index:999; 
    }

    .footermenu ul { 
        justify-content: space-between; 
        display: flex;
    }

    .menu-item > ul.sub-menu {  
        padding: 1vh;
        text-align: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    }

    .menu > .menu-item:not(:first-child):not(:last-child), .menu-item:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) > ul.sub-menu {  
        text-align: center !important;
    flex: 0 1 33%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 33%;
    }

    .menu > .menu-item:first-child, .menu-item:first-child > ul.sub-menu {  
        text-align: left !important;
    flex: 0 1 33%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 33%;
    }

    .menu > .menu-item:last-child, .menu-item:last-child > ul.sub-menu {  
        text-align: right !important;
    flex: 0 1 33%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 33%;
    }
    
    /* from here on I am translating the sub-menu items up */

    .footermenu .menu-item:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) > ul.sub-menu {  
    -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 15vh));
        transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 15vh));
    }

    .footermenu .menu-item:first-child > ul.sub-menu {  
    -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 15vh));
        transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 15vh));
    }

    .footermenu .menu-item:last-child > ul.sub-menu {  
    -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 15vh));
        transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 15vh));
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
         h1  {
             font-size:6vw;
      letter-spacing: 0.02em;
          }
         h2, h3, ul.sub-menu a {
      font-size:3.6vw;
       line-height: 1.2em;
      color: black;
      }
   
  
     #content {
      margin: auto;
      width: 68vw
      margin-top: 25vh;
      }
    
    }
@media screen and (min-width: 1550px) {
         h1  {
             font-size:3.5vw;
                letter-spacing: 0.02em;
          }
         h2, h3, ul.sub-menu a {
      font-size:2.3vw;
       line-height: 1.2em;
      color: black;
      }
     .post .entry-content {
      margin-top: 1.5em;
      text-align:left;
      -webkit-column-count:1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
          column-count: 1;
      }
     .footermenu  {
      z-index:999;  
      height: 18vh!important; /*I am trying to fix the problem like this  but as said before this is not safe */
      }
       .post .entry-content { 
     -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
         column-count: 3;
     } 
     #content {
     margin: auto;
     width: 68vw;
     margin-top: 25vh;
     }
    }
```

```html
 <div id="footer">
    <h1>  
        <div class="footermenu"> 
            <ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_4">Contact</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_a">More  Landscapes</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_b">Collection</a></li></ul>
              </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_5">Links</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_a">More Landscapes</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_b">Collection</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_c">Brave New</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_d">Line Three</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_e">Mary's World</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6">About</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_a">More  Landscapes</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_b">Collection</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_c">Brave New</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_d">Line Three</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_e">Mary's World</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </h1>
 </div><!-- end of #footer -->
```

Would you be able to help me place this footer always on the same position, regardless on the number of sum-menu items, viewport dimensions and font-size?

A php approach for wordpress engine is also welcome.
So in summary:
I am trying to change the html order of my footer menu in such a way the parent menu item appears after its children. I have done it using CSS "transform: translateY(n)" however this does not solve my problem completely because this method has way too many variables. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into the specifics of your very detailed requirements, what I think you are essentially wanting the menus to be is botton-up.

Since you are using flexbox this is just a matter of using `flex-direction:column-reverse`.

A general example.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
.footermenu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.footermenu #menu-footer-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu-footer-menu > li > a {
  color: red;
}
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="footermenu">
    <ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_4">Contact</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_a">More  Landscapes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_b">Collection</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_5">Links</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_a">More Landscapes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_b">Collection</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_c">Brave New</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_d">Line Three</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_e">Mary's World</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_a">More  Landscapes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_b">Collection</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_c">Brave New</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_d">Line Three</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="url_6_e">Mary's World</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of #footer -->
```

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need to use transform here. Just put the sub-menu ul in code before the main menu header `<a>` tag for footer menus. No need of height in menu-footer-menu and also you need to seperately set each main menu li to position:absolute to keep it to the bottom.

Here is what i turned your code into. I think this is what you needed.

http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/jModxK

Hope it makes sense. Let me know if need more help.

P.S. I think i helped you fix the menu left, center and right alignments in another question. Didn't I? :)

Comment: Thanks. This would do it Nasir, but unfortunately the html structure is generated dynamically by a wordpress php file which needs to be updated every once and a while. I cannot therefore change it: it would only work until it would be updated by Wordpress. Yes you did help fix the alignments. Thanks again. :)